# How is this causing an endless loop?

Tags: c#, infinite-loop, messagebox, visual-studio-debugging, mutual-recursion

Some legacy code I'm stuck maintaining is stuck in an infinite loop (and thus I myself seem to be in one); I can't figure out why/how, though.

Here's the app's entry point, where it instantiates the main form (frmCentral):

**CODE EXHIBIT A**

```
public static int Main(string [] args)
{
    try
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;

        currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(GlobalExceptionHandler);

        string name = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Executing assembly is {0}", name)); // TODO: Remove after testing <= this one is seen
        IntPtr mutexHandle = CreateMutex(IntPtr.Zero, true, name);
        long error = GetLastError();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Last error int was {0}", error.ToString())); // TODO: Remove after testing <= this one is also seen

        if (error == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);

            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("#NETCF_AGL_BASE_", null);
            if ((int) hWnd > 0)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);  
            }
            return 0;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("made it into Main method #4"); // TODO: Remove after testing <= this one is seen

        ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);

        MessageBox.Show("made it into Main method #5"); // TODO: Remove after testing <= this one is seen

        DeviceInfo devIn = DeviceInfo.GetInstance();

        MessageBox.Show("made it into Main method #6"); // TODO: Remove after testing <= this one is seen

        Wifi.DisableWifi();

        MessageBox.Show("made it into Main method #7"); // TODO: Remove after testing <= this one is seen

        // Instantiate a new instance of Form1.
        frmCentral f1 = new frmCentral();
        f1.Height = devIn.GetScreenHeight();
        f1.Text = SSCS.GetFormTitle("SSCS HHS", "", "");

        MessageBox.Show("made it before Application.Run() in Main method"); // TODO: Remove after testing <= this one is NOT seen
        Application.Run(f1);

        devIn.Close();

        Application.Exit();
        return 0;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SSCS.ExceptionHandler(ex, "Main");
        return 0;
    }
} // Main() method
```

frmCentral's constructor then calls a (what's the opposite of glorified?) singleton method named *DBConnection.GetInstance()*:

**CODE EXHIBIT B**

```
public frmCentral()
{
    try
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("made it past InitializeComponent() in frmCentral constructor"); // <= this displays
        devIn = DeviceInfo.GetInstance();
        MessageBox.Show("made it past DeviceInfo.GetInstance() in frmCentral constructor"); // <= this displays
        dbconn = DBConnection.GetInstance();
        MessageBox.Show("made it past DBConnection.GetInstance() in frmCentral constructor");
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        UpdateMenuItemSelectable = false;
        ResetConnectionFetchForm = false;

        AllowNewItems = true;

        listboxWork.Focus();
        MessageBox.Show("made it through frmCentral constructor"); // <= this one does NOT display
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SSCS.ExceptionHandler(ex, "frmCentral()");
    }
} // frmCentral Constructor
```

Here's that "glorified" sort-of/kind-of singleton method:

**CODE EXHIBIT C**

```
// Singleton pattern, or at least a derivation thereof
public static DBConnection GetInstance()
{
    MessageBox.Show("made it into DBConnection.GetInstance()");
    try
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("made it into DBConnection.GetInstance(); instance was null");
            instance = new DBConnection();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SSCS.ExceptionHandler(ex, "DBConnection.GetInstance");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

That instantiates DBConnection and so its constructor is called:

**CODE EXHIBIT D**

```
private DBConnection()
{
    try
    {
        // Connection String
        string conStr = "Data Source = " + filename;
        string cmpStr = conStr + ".tmp";
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("made it into DBConnection constructor. cmpStr == {0}", cmpStr)); // TODO: Comment out or remove
        if (File.Exists(filename+".tmp"))
            File.Delete(filename+".tmp");

        engine = new SqlCeEngine(conStr);
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("SqlCeEngine created. conStr == {0}", conStr)); // TODO: Comment out or remove

        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("file {0} exists", filename)); // TODO: Comment out or remove
        }
        else
        {
            // Create the SQL Server CE database
            engine.CreateDatabase();
            MessageBox.Show("Made it past call to engine.CreateDatabase()"); // TODO: Comment out or remove
        }
        engine.Dispose();

        objCon = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
        MessageBox.Show("Made it past call to new SqlCeConnection(conStr)"); // TODO: Comment out or remove

        objCon.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SSCS.ExceptionHandler(ex, "DBConnection.DBConnection");
    }
}
```

I see the *MessageBox.Show()*s from Code Exhibit A (unless otherwise noted), then the same for Code Exhibit B, then Code Exhibit C, then Code Exhibit D, then it goes back and forth between C and D "until the cows come home."

I don't see why the DBConnection constructor and the DBConnection GetInstance() recursively call each other, though...is there a needle in the haystack I'm missing, or an elephant hidden in plain sight, or...???

### UPDATE

```
public static void ExceptionHandler(Exception ex, string location)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.Message + "\n\nLocation: " + location, GetFormTitle("SSCS: " + ex.GetType().FullName,"",""));
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Handler generated an exception!\n" + exc.Message + "\n\nCalling Location: " + location, GetFormTitle("SSCS: " + exc.GetType().FullName,"",""));
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Here's more edifying obscurities:

```
public static string GetFormTitle(string formName, string serialNo, string siteNo)
{

    string titleBar = formName == "" ? "SSCS HHS" : formName;

    if((serialNo == ""))
    {
        User person = new User();
        person.getUserFromTable();
        serialNo = person.getSerialNo();
    }

    if (frmCentral.HashSiteMapping.ContainsKey(siteNo))
    {
        siteNo = (string) frmCentral.HashSiteMapping[siteNo];
    }


    if (serialNo != "")
        titleBar += " - " + serialNo + (siteNo == "" ? "" : " Site #" + siteNo);

    return titleBar;
}
```

### UPDATE 3

The uncaught exception code I added:

```
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(GlobalExceptionHandler);

static void GlobalExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("GlobalExceptionHandler caught {0}; Compact Framework Version == {1}", e.Message, Environment.Version.ToString()));
}
```

I have not seen any evidence that this handler is ever reached, though (so far, anyway).

### UPDATE 4

Very interesting - after adding a MessageBox.Show (or two) to GetFormTitle:

```
public static string GetFormTitle(string formName, string serialNo, string siteNo)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("GetFormTitle() reached. formName == {0}; serialNo == {1}; siteNo == {2}", formName, serialNo, siteNo)); // TODO: Remove after testing
    string titleBar = formName == "" ? "SSCS HHS" : formName;

    if((serialNo == ""))
    {
        User person = new User();
        person.getUserFromTable();
        serialNo = person.getSerialNo();
    }

    if (frmCentral.HashSiteMapping.ContainsKey(siteNo))
    {
        siteNo = (string) frmCentral.HashSiteMapping[siteNo];
    }


    if (serialNo != "")
        titleBar += " - " + serialNo + (siteNo == "" ? "" : " Site #" + siteNo);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("titleBar val about to be returned. Val is {0}", titleBar)); // TODO: Remove after testing
    return titleBar;
}
```

...these are the sequence of of MessageBox.Show()s that I see now:

```
0) Made it into DBConnection.GetInstance() 
1) Made it into DBConnection.GetInstance() instance was null
2) Made it to DBConnection constructor cmpStr == ....
3) Sqlceengine created. conStr == ...
4) File \My Documents\HHSDB.SDF exists
5) Made it past call to new SqlCeConnection(conStr)
6) GetFormTitle() reached. fromName == SSCS:
System.Data.SqlserverCe.SqlCeException; serial No ==; siteNo ==
```

...followed by a round of more tail-chasing, recursive messages until I warm-boot (I hate to contradict the Fab 4, but contrary to popular opinion, Happiness is decidedly NOT a warm boot!*)

...so right in the midst of a MessageBox message display, an exception is inserted! Wholly Pennsylvania Hip-Hop (Key Rap)!

```
* Let's have no attempts at humor revolving around warm booty, now!
```

**That was a superlative show of remote desk debugging, LB2!**

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436775/how-is-this-causing-an-endless-loop

Comment: I could spend the rest of the day on that.

Comment: My first suggestion would be: "don't debug with Alert". Use `System.Diagnostics.WriteLine` and watch the debug window while running. `Alert` will cause execution to halt. Or if you need to halt execution, set a breakpoint and step through.

Comment: Breakpoints not possible in this project/setup (if only there were). This is a CE/CF project that runs on ancient devices.

Comment: I don't see it, but one of the reason for saying don't debug with `Alert` is because with the one after `if (instance == null)` any other attempt to access `GetInstance()` is going to pile up additional alerts after that. So I suspect it's not the case that case that `DBConnection` is calling `GetInstance`, but that something else is calling `GetInstance` multiple times and, because of the alert, they all end up calling `DBConnection`. Are you absolutely certain that this is the only place `GetInstance` gets called?

Comment: @MattBurland: Hec Ramsey no! GetInstance() is called from a jillion places, but I don't see how they are getting the opportunity on startup to do so...

Comment: @MattBurland: I also don't understand why every time GetInstance is called, "instance" is null - why nil it willy-nilly like that? And why the main form has a DBConnection var that it assigns the value of DBConnection's DBConnection "instance" var to - why not just the public "instance" directly? The whole architecture/thought process behind this BBOM drives me batty.

Comment: If you can't use breakpoints, and GetInstance() is called from a jillion places, I suggest using StackTrace to write out who is calling GetInstance. That will probably tell you very quickly why it's getting called multiple times.

Comment: What does `SSCS.ExceptionHandler` do internally?  does it rethrow?  Is it possible that `objCon.Open();` throws, which possibly makes exception bubble up, implies that `instance` never gets set.  And thus _"gazillion places where `GetInstance` get's called"_ makes it appear that it is an infinite loop?

Comment: My best suggestion would be to refactor `GetInstance` into a proper singleton pattern with thread-safety and see if that makes the problem go away. Either that or hunt down the original developer and punch them in the nose.

Comment: Actually, another suggestion would be a double check on null. Silly as it sounds, add another `if(instance==null)` *after* your alert. If that stops the alerts from `DBConnection` then you know the problem is that you have a race condition on calling `GetInstance`. If you still see (more than one set of) alerts from `DBConnection`, then `instance` must be getting set to null somewhere.

Comment: @MattBurland: Tempting, but he has absquatulated to nether regions. To be fair, though, as one coder I formerly worked with noted once, "Everybody is an idiot after they leave, no matter how revered they were while they were there."

Comment: @MattBurland: "instance must be getting set to null somewhere" Yes, it is; don't understand why, and don't want to change things more than absolutely necessary, as this is definitely a "whack-a-mole" situation and "you break it (more), you bought it"

Comment: Chaser to my earlier comment:   Can you please post `SSCS.ExceptionHandler` body as I suspect the secret is there?  Oh, and also, put debug messages in relevant catches so you can see if exception is being thrown or not.

Comment: @LB2: I put it in UPDATE

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Oh my, a try/catch around messagebox only for the catch to show a messagebox with just about the same construct!!!  Precious!  This needs to go into some sort of archive of book of records... :)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Question:  Can `GetFormTitle` throw or cause an exception? If yes, it's possible you're not seeing the msgboxes in your catch, and yet keep having them.  Can you try replace catch's message box with a very plain one that doesn't call anything else? (I am grasping at straws here too)

Comment: @LB2: If you saw the rest of your code, your hair would fall out and your toes would involuntarily curl back.

Comment: @LB2: Going back a few comments, if objCon.Open(); "threw" I would see the catch block's message, right?

Comment: @MattBurland: "because of the alert, they all end up calling DBConnection" Why would the MessageBox cause DBConnection to be called? The app had been endless-looping prior to my adding the MessageBoxes; they show me just what code is being reached, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51913/discussion-between-lb2-and-b-clay-shannon)

Comment: Because you have the alert *after* the null check but *before* you assign a value to .

Comment: New related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505211/which-sqlserverce-dll-version-do-i-need-to-reference-in-my-project-to-match-what

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what's likely going on <strike>(at this point is a theory until OP can confirm)</strike>:

### The thing that starts the problem...

The issue that starts the infinite loop chain is likely `objCon.Open();` in Exhibit D.  There is probably some issue with connecting to the database, and the `Open()` call, as it should, throws an exception.  This of course get caught in the local `catch` that is immediately following that line.

The local `catch` calls `SSCS.ExceptionHandler` which is shown in Update 1.  It looks benign, but in it hides the culprit's accomplice by the name `GetFormTitle` which is shown in Update 2.

### Where things take a turn for the worse...

`GetFormTitle` has a very interesting piece of code:

```
User person = new User();
person.getUserFromTable();
```

... which most likely is a model retrieving user info from the database (where else).

### And so the infinite loop is created...

Well, to get `User` from database, one needs a connection, which most likely causes `DBConnection.GetInstance()` to be called, which gets to `objCon.Open();` which starts the new cycle, and thus an [infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23437813/1556108) is created (ingeniously, without using any of language's built-in looping mechanisms, to be duly noted).

### To confirm:

OP: Please put very plain *(meaning no calls to `GetFormTitle`, please)* MessageBoxes in the `GetFormTitle`, and if the above theory is right, you'll see it in the path of execution.

Comment: Please see update 4 for confirmation of your genius/tenacity.

Comment: Thanks for posting the confirmation of the theory.  And enjoy your well earned weekend! ;)

Comment: "and thus an infinite loop is created (ingeniously, without using any of language's built-in looping mechanisms, to be duly noted)"
It's not a bug - it's a feature! Maybe I should componentize it and make a fortune on support revenue.